# Directional derivative $f(x,y) = x^3+y^2 -2xy$ and $a=(1,1)^T$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = x^3+y^2 -2xy$ and $a=(1,1)^T$.

How can one find out the directional derivative of $f$ in $a$ in the direction of northwest with the definition and with the help of the gradient?

The gradient is

$$\text{grad}(f) = \left(\begin{array}{c}3x^2-2y \\2y-2x\end{array}\right)$$

I don't know if this is correct, but to get the directional derivative one has to put the values of the gradient in the point $a=(1,1)^T$, so we get

$$\text{grad}(f)(1,1) = \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0 \end{array}\right)$$

Transposing it gives

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 & 0  \end{array}\right)$$

I have read that northwest is $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\begin{array}{c}-1\\1\end{array}\right)$

Then we look if the length of the vector is $1$.

$$|r| = 2$$

$2 \neq 1$, so we normalize the vector via

$$v = \frac{1}{|r|} \cdot r = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = 1$$

And then we calculate the dot product with

$$D_vf(a) = \text{grad}(f)(1,1) \cdot v$$

$$= \left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0 \end{array}\right) \cdot 1$$

$$= 1$$

I think this is wrong, but I just follwed the "algorithm"..

Comment: The gradient of $f$ only has 2 entries, since it is defined on $\Bbb R^2$, so $\nabla(f)=grad(f)={3x^2-2y \choose 2y-2x}$

Comment: @Norse Sorry, my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the gradient of $f$ at a point $(x,y)$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3x^2-2y\\2y-2x\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. So, the gradient of $f$ at $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Since northeast is (indeed) $\frac1{\sqrt2}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, the partial derivative in that direction is$$\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=-\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: Thanks José. Is it also possible to come to that answer without using the gradient?

Comment: Yes. Use the definition of directional derivative.

Comment: You mean evaluating $D_vf(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h \cdot v) - f(x)}{h}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 use this method when  question is in form https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304472/computing-the-directional-derivative otherwise in polynomial type question i prefer to go with gradient mehod.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos when applying proper defination method which is mentioned in above comment of java ,it is neccessery that $v$ vector should be unit?

Comment: No, it is not. ${}$

Comment: @TheStudent Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you tell me in which direction the partial derivative is maximal? I don't know where I can find the values for northeast, west etc..

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.